# How to get the previous text before a regex match?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having difficulty of getting the text before a regex match. This is my input text for example:

```
Tytuł Płatnosci: FK 1048388520 F 1048393748
Kontr. : AUTO-BLAK SP. Z O. O.
FARBIARSKA 25A
WARSZAWA
Nr Banku: 17501123 RAIFF Centrum Operacyjne
Nr Rachunku: 06175000090000000010263654
Data Stempla 170906
Kwota Przekazu: 88.30 PLN
Info Code; 0003677116
06.09.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 06.09.17 100.00
Referencje : PL0INE117249DJ20
Nr Ref: 4249174665
Tytuł Płatnosci: faktura vat 1048399482
Kontr. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO
```

And my search string is : Kontr. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO
I have to get the string before it : Tytuł Płatnosci: faktura vat 1048399482

**I don't have a code as I'm using an automation software with regex component.**

I tried this pattern:

```
((.*\n){1})Kontr. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO
```

However, it doesn't return the output I want, it returns the other one with "Tytul", I just want to return the text before Kontr. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO and not the rest of the text.

Hope you can help me with this. Thank you

Comment: You have `Tytuł Płatnosci: faktura vat 1048399482` in `match.Groups[1].Value`. Show the code.

Comment: Is the `Kontr. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO` a static value? You need to escape the `.` to match a literal `.`.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I don't have a code as I'm using an automation software with regex component. Kontr. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO is a static value

Comment: I need the regular expression not the C# Code.

Comment: Cool, see my solution below.

Comment: Can you format the input? It's important where your newlines are....

Comment: Hi Marc, it's formatted now. Someone did it for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no access to code, you need a regex only solution. Use a positive lookahead:

```
(?-s).+(?=[\r\n]+Kontr\. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO)
       ^^^                                       ^
```

or

```
[^\r\n]+(?=[\r\n]+Kontr\. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f-s%29.%2b%28%3f%3d%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%2bKontr%5c.+%3a+FIRMA+HANDLOWA+TOP-ZOO%29&i=Tytu%c5%82+P%c5%82atnosci%3a+FK+1048388520+F+1048393748%0d%0aKontr.+%3a+AUTO-BLAK+SP.+Z+O.+O.%0d%0aFARBIARSKA+25A%0d%0aWARSZAWA%0d%0aNr+Banku%3a+17501123+RAIFF+Centrum+Operacyjne%0d%0aNr+Rachunku%3a+06175000090000000010263654%0d%0aData+Stempla+170906%0d%0aKwota+Przekazu%3a+88.30+PLN%0d%0aInfo+Code%3b+0003677116%0d%0a06.09.17+PRZELEW+PRZYCHODZACY+06.09.17+100.00%0d%0aReferencje+%3a+PL0INE117249DJ20%0d%0aNr+Ref%3a+4249174665%0d%0aTytu%c5%82+P%c5%82atnosci%3a+faktura+vat+1048399482%0d%0aKontr.+%3a+FIRMA+HANDLOWA+TOP-ZOO)

**Details**

- `(?-s)` - turn off the Singleline mode (when `.` matches newline symbols)
- `.+` - any 1 or more chars other than newline, as many as possible (I doubt you are interested in extracting an empty string, thus, I used `+` quantifier, if you are interested in cases when the line is empty, use `.*` instead) (**NOTE**: if you want to avoid matching trailing CR symbols, replace `.` with `[^\r\n]`)
- `(?=[\r\n]+Kontr\. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO)` - a positive lookahead that requires its pattern to match immediately to the right of the current position:

  - `[\r\n]+` - 1 or more CR and/or LF symbols
  - `Kontr\. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO` - a `Kontr. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO` substring.

Comment: If the spaces round `:` can be arbitrary, you might even use `\s*:\s*` instead of `" : "`.

Comment: Still gets the rest of the strings upwards: This is the output:

Comment: Tytuł Płatnosci: FK 1048388520 F 1048393748
Kontr. : AUTO-BLAK SP. Z O. O.
FARBIARSKA 25A
WARSZAWA
Nr Banku: 17501123 RAIFF Centrum Operacyjne
Nr Rachunku: 06175000090000000010263654
Data Stempla 170906
Kwota Przekazu: 88.30 PLN
Info Code; 0003677116
06.09.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 06.09.17 100.00
Referencje : PL0INE117249DJ20
Nr Ref: 4249174665
Tytuł Płatnosci: faktura vat 1048399482

Comment: Looks like you have to add `(?-s)` in front of the pattern.

Comment: Got it! What does (?-s) for? It worked now! You're great!

Comment: I added two possible solutions. The `(?-s)` makes sure `.` will not match LF (newline chars). I described why `[^\r\n]+` can be better than `.+` in the details section.